# Conditional formatting Grand total in a matrix- Power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am looking at changing color for the total field in a matrix table, the total field is a Column subtotal done in power bi formatting.

I want to be able to change the color depending on the line results.
[image: Image example]

so basically if the first total is less than 100 then red if more then green, second total if less then 3 then green else red and so goes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating Power bi didn't allow the color formatting until the recent version.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26442337)

Comment: @DawidRutkowski that is the answer.